# passing values from page to bootstrap modal and action result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an asp.net MVC 4 application. I am using bootstrap to show modal. In my index view, I have a rdiobutton list, a dropdown and a textbox and search button. When user will click search, I want to show bootstrap modal with values selected/types on main page and there will be some more textboxes on modal popup. How can I open the bootstrap using jquery and pass values to bootstrap popup ?

```
    <input type="radio" name="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">New
     <input type="radio" name="inlineCheckbox1" value="option2">Used                   
     <input type="radio" name="inlineCheckbox1" value="option3">Both

     <select id="myselect">
      <option>   option 1   </option>
      <option>   option 2   </option>
      <option>   option 3   </option>
      <option>   option 4   </option>
     </select

  <input class="span4" id="MonthlyPayment" type="text">

  <button id="btnAdvanceSearch" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="height: 40px; font-size: xx-large"><b>Search</b></button></td>


 @Html.Partial("~/views/Home/_AdvanceSearch.cshtml")
```

and my partial view is like a this

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width:700px">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "frmSearchVehicles" }))
    {


 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DownPayment, new { @class = "span4" }) 
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DownPayment1, new { @class = "span4" }) 
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DownPayment2, new { @class = "span4" }) 
<input type="submt" value="search"
}
```

1)How can I open modal popup using jquery
2) how can I pass radio button, select and textbox value to modal popup
3) How can I pass all the values ( the ones radio button, select and textbox value on main page and modal popup) to action method ?

Please suggest

Answer (score -4, accepted):

To show the dialog modal use the following:

```
$( "#myModal" ).modal('show');
```

Secondly,

To be able to pass your values to an action all you have to do is create a SearchCriteria  Model class with the names of your inputs as properties

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchCriteria model)
{

}
```

The problem is that your form is inside the modal, this is why you're not being able to pass them to the Action, what you need to do is put your Form outside the modal, this way when you post everything gets posted along, and you wouldn't have to pass the values to the modal itself.

Comment: i am using bootstrap modal not jquery ui moda., also, how to pass values to bootstrap modal from page and then pass those values to action result ? I am able to pass values from bootstrap inputs to action result but not the ones which are on main page.

Comment: That's because the ones in the modal are in a different form tag, what you need to is put the search form outside of the modal

Comment: so i should put html.beginform around main page including modal popup ?

Comment: All your form inputs should be inside your form tag, so yes, the BeginForm should be in the mainpage !